# Best solution to represent Data[i,j] in c?

Tags: c, data-structures

There is a pseudocode that I want to implement in C. But I am in doubt on how to implement a part of it. The psuedocode is:

```
for every pair of states qi, and qj, i<j, do
    D[i,j] := 0
    S[i,j] := notzero
end for
```

`i` and `j`, in `qi` and `qj` are subscripts.

how do I represent `D[i,J]` or `S[i,j]`. which data structure to use so that its simple and fast.

Comment: Use a two-dimensional array in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```
int length= 10;
int i =0, j= 0;
int res1[10][10] = {0, }; //index is based on "length" value
int res2[10][10] = {0, }; //index is based on "length" value
```

and then

```
for (i =0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (j =0; j < length; j++)
    {
        res1[i][j] = 0;
        res2[i][j] = 1;//notzero
    }
}
```

Here `D[i,j]` and `S[i,j]` are represented by `res1[10][10]` and `res2[10][10]`, respectively. These are called *two-dimentional array*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `struct` will be your friend here depending on what you actually want to work with.
Struct would be fine if, say, pair of states creates some kind of entity. 
Otherwise You could use two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer.

Depending on coding goals and platform, to get "simple and fast" using a [pointer to pointer to a number](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+**y) may be faster then a [2-D array](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+x%5B3%5D%5B4%5D) in C.

```
// 2-D array
double x[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];

// Code computes the address in `x`, often involving a i*MAX_COL, if not in a loop.
// Slower when multiplication is expensive and random array access occurs.
x[i][j] = f();

// pointer to pointer of double
double **y = calloc(MAX_ROW, sizeof *y);
for (i=0; i<MAX_ROW; i++) y[i] = calloc(MAX_COL, sizeof *(y[i]));

// Code computes the address in `y` by a lookup of y[i]
y[i][j] = f();
```

Flexibility

The first data type is easy `print(x)`, when the array size is fixed, but becomes challenging otherwise.

The 2nd data type is easy `print(y, rows, columns)`, when the array size is variable and of course works well with fixed.

The 2nd data type also row swapping simply by swapping pointers.

---

So if code is using a fixed array size, use `double x[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL]`, otherwise recommend `double **y`. [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV)

Comment: I doubt a jagged array could ever be faster than a plain 2D array. Do you have an example ?